# SQL Server nested queries syntax

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

I hope someone can explain why this query is giving me an error and how I could solve it.
This is the syntax:

```
With ID as ( 
select ID1 from.... where.... group by.....
), TYDATA as (

   with MG as (
   select IDMG, * from.... where.... group by.....
   ), TY as (
   select ID1, IDMG, * from.... where.... group by.....
   )
   SELECT TY.*, MG.* 
FROM TY LEFT JOIN MG ON TY.IDMG = MG.IDMG

)
SELECT ID.*, TYDATA.* 
FROM ID LEFT JOIN TYDATA.ID1 ON ID.ID1=TYDATA.ID1
```

The error is "incorrect syntax" near the second with.
If I run each query separately I receive no errors so I am guessing the syntax of this join is wrong.
Could you please help me understand the error as well as provide me an alternative way on how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTEs' definitions cannot be nested. A previously defined CTE can be used in a subsequent one, but it should be defined on the top level.

As such, the structure should be like this:

```sql
With ID as ( 
  select ID1 from.... where.... group by.....
),
MG as (
  select IDMG, * from.... where.... group by.....
),
TY as (
  select ID1, IDMG, * from.... where.... group by.....
),
TYDATA as (
  SELECT TY.*, MG.* 
  FROM TY LEFT JOIN MG ON TY.IDMG = MG.IDMG
)
SELECT ID.*, TYDATA.* 
FROM ID LEFT JOIN TYDATA.ID1 ON ID.ID1=TYDATA.ID1
```

Comment: Thank you Roger, for providing the solution as well as the explanation.